# Django - dynamic form creation from random db entries

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-validation

This is an oversimplified example of what am I trying to achieve. Let's say I have these two models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

And let's say I have thousands of questions in the database, but I want each user to answer only a few random ones. So, my idea was to create a dynamic form. Something like this:

```
class QuestionnaireForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionnaireForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        questions = list(Question.objects.all())
        random.shuffle(questions) # it successfully validates without this line
        questions = questions[:3]

        for q in questions:
            self.fields[q.text] = forms.CharField()
```

When I do this, I get my three random questions as desired, but the form won't validate. If I comment out shuffling, everything works fine, but then I get the same questions every time, obviously.

From what I can see, it seems like Django is calling the __init__ method again on form submission and thus repeating the shuffling and getting different questions. I tried reading through the documentation, but I'm not managing to wrap my head around why is this the way it is.

Comment: Of course it calls init on submission; that's what your view does.

Answer (score 1):

[Random ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by):

```
questions = Question.objects.all().order_by('?')[:3]
```

To validate form, it hink, you need restore same queryset with something like:

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(pk__in=request.POST.getlist('ids'))
```

and put it to form. Think you need also save same ordering — then you can sort out this list in form.

**Update:**

You should save state between requests some way. You can add hidden field, add URL parameters, set cookie, save info in user's profile — is up to your choice. Tipical way is set hidden inputs (generally it's default django [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) behavior).

So on first request, when you show form — you get queryset, sort it by `pk` for example, put to form and add hidden fields with IDs. When user made POST request with answer — you'll restore your queryset with this IDs, sort it again same way and put to form to validate.

Comment: It is not only about the random ordering but getting the same questions again when the form is posted. This approach would also generate different questions in GET and POST requests.

Comment: Nope. The problem remains. I used _random.shuffle_ for efficiency, but it's doing basically the same thing.

Comment: I already knew I needed to restore the same qs to make it work, but I'm not really sure how. Are you suggesting me to put a list of ids as a hidden input into the form? I would be grateful if you could elaborate a bit on this.

Comment: @ЛудиМачак i've updated answer with detailed description.